# White space in URL when using AJAX with google static maps

Tags: google-maps, iframe, google-maps-static-api

I have a page that has an instance of Google statics maps embedded in an iFrame.  When the page loads, the initial instance of this iFrame loads a set location.  There is a list of addresses on the page that the user can click on and based on their choice, the iFrame with the embedded Google maps is reloaded through AJAX.

I am having some trouble with loading the new URL.  Below is the PHP I am currently using

```
$database->mysqlquery("SELECT street_address
                       FROM favorites
                       WHERE id = $row_id");

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($database->results)){
    $address = $row[street_address];
}

$url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=$address&zoom
=18&size=640x640&sensor=false";
```

I get the address from my database and assign it to a variable.  I then pass the variable into the static maps URL.

With the url defined, I call an iFrame

```
<iframe width = "425" height = "315" frameborder = "0" scrolling = "no" 
marginheight = "0" marginwidth = "0" src= "<?php echo $url; ?>" id = "iframe"></iframe>
```

The iFrame does not load when I directly hit the php page or call the page through AJAX.  When I inspect the page using Chrome or Firefox, I see the following source

```
<iframe width="425" height="315" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" 
marginheight="0" `marginwidth="0" 
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=116 Ponce De Leon Ave 
NE, Atlanta, GA&amp;zoom=18&amp;size=640x640&amp;sensor=false" id="iframe"></iframe>
```

If I take the src string from the above and load the link through the browser directly, the map loads.

Why is my iFrame not loading?

**Update**

New iFrame HTML after adding rawurlencode() to encode $address variable

```
<iframe width="425" height="315" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" 
marginwidth="0" 
src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap? 
center=116%20Ponce%20De%20Leon%20Ave%20NE%2C%20Atlanta%2C%20GA&amp;
zoom=18&amp;size=640x640&amp;sensor=false" id="iframe"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must encode the street_address, e.g. via [`rawurlencode()`](http://php.net/rawurlencode)

Spaces are not allowed in a URL(it works when you use the URL with spaces directly in a browser, because most browsers automatically encode the URLs)

Comment: I added the rawurlencode() function to encode the $address variable.  I am still having trouble getting the map to load.  The src now has formatted spaces, but the map still does not display.  If I copy the link in the new src and go to it using my browser, the map shows

Comment: **1st:** there are still whitespaces and linebreaks in the URL. **Then:** The returned file is an image, not a HTML-Document! And the server sends a `x-frame-options-header` which is set to **same-origin**, therefore you can't use it as a iframe-src. Use an `<img/>` instead of the `<iframe/>`

Comment: Awww, you are right indeed.  It needed to be enclosed in img and not iframe.  The linebreaks in the above were added so I could better display the code

Comment: One question though, the default map I load on my page (not through AJAX) uses an iFrame to display the map.  Any reason why I need to use 'img src' on the AJAX loaded page, but not on the default page?

Comment: I'm not sure what you load on the other page, but what you load here is an image, when you want to use an iframe you'll need to use another URL, e.g. provided by the embed-code on http://maps.google.com